# Bulk Load CSV into Hbase using MapReduce

Tags: csv, hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hbase

I am trying to bulk load data from CSV to HBASE table as guided in this link: http://www.thecloudavenue.com/2013/04/bulk-loading-data-in-hbase.html

I have created the JAR of the code and running in terminal with following command:

```
hadoop jar ~/hadoop/BLoad.jar anoop.BLDriver /input/path /op/path NBAFinal2010
```

but while execution i get stuck up as the zookeeper gives following errors:

```
15/09/23 22:29:45 INFO client.RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=10, retries=35, started=48674 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=
```

This goes on for 35 tries.
After that I get:

```
Wed Sep 23 22:28:57 IST 2015,       RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1443027536828, pause=100, retries=35}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: 
com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.FailedServerException: This server is in the failed servers list: Anoop-PC/127.0.1.1:16000
```

also,

```
Wed Sep 23 22:37:48 IST 2015, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1443027536828, pause=100, retries=35}, 
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.getInputStream(Ljava/net/Socket;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/net/SocketInputWrapper;

at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:147)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.executeMasterCallable(HTable.java:596)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.getTableDescriptor(HTable.java:572)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.HFileOutputFormat.configureIncrementalLoad(HFileOutputFormat.java:91)
at anoop.hbase.BLDriver.run(BLDriver.java:60)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
at anoop.hbase.BLDriver.main(BLDriver.java:32)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
```

not sure whats going on. Please help.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly says that the Master is not running. Zookeeper comes in between HMaster and region servers. So the issue seems to be the link between HMaster and Zookeeper. Verify your Hbase config settings. Some links to help and resolve in different ways. Not sure, how you have installed and configured Hbase. So you can use any link here

[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269721/error-org-apache-hadoop-hbase-masternotrunningexception-nullhbasehadoop)
[link2](https://support.pivotal.io/hc/communities/public/questions/200372678-create-hbase-tables-pl-erroring-out-Problem-resolved-after-starting-the-hbase-master-)
[link3](http://hortonworks.com/community/forums/topic/org-apache-hadoop-hbase-masternotrunningexception/)
[link4](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Storage-Random-Access-HDFS/hbase-MasterNotRunningException/td-p/2499)

Comment: Can you please point out which setting may be causing this? I am new to HBase and am not sure about this. thanks